# Eloquent - Many To Many, users-topics delete all topics by user id

Tags: mysql, laravel, many-to-many, eloquent, laravel-5

Given Eloquent Many To Many relationship:

Migration:

```
class Topics extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('topics', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });

        Schema::create('topic_user', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('topic_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('topic_id')->references('id')->on('topics');
        });
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Topic', 'topic_user');
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how can I delete all topics by given user, currently my code looks like this:

```
Auth::user()->topics()->delete();
```

But I'm getting exception:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "topic_user" LINE 1: delete
>   from "topics" where "topic_user"."user_id" = $1 ^ (SQL: delete from
>   "topics" where "topic_user"."user_id" = 6)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would try looping through each topic and then running `$topic->delete();`.  See if that works

Comment: @limonte if i understand correctly, a topic can only have one creator as user ? is it so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple:

```
Auth::user()->topics()->detach();
```

Comment: There's a different between detaching all related models and actually deleting them... (But I'm not sure what the OP actually wants)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! Sorry for delayed response.

Comment: @limonte "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead`.`topic_user`, CONSTRAINT `topic_user_topic_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`topic_id`) REFERENCES `topics` (`id`)) (SQL: delete `topics` from `topics` inner join `topic_user` on `topics`.`id` = `topic_user`.`topic_id` where `topic_user`.`user_id` = 1)"

this is what i get when try to delete. i tried with sync to but i still don't get it. after deleting related rows from topic_user it's not possible delete due to absence of relation from the topics table

Comment: @limonte can you share the last version of your exact code. i still don't get it what are you trying to do ?